# can't figure out the right hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have made 3 buttons on my page that shows an img.
I want the image to be shown when people get over the button cald HTML, CSS or JS & Jquery.
But the problem is that when you hover over the image, (that you can't see yet), you can see it aswell.

This is my website where I use it: [My School Report.](http://rdv-design.com/stageverslag2/home.html)

When you get over the Tie, a box shows up. Scroll down and you can see the buttons.

Here is the HTML code I use for 1 of the buttons:

```
<div id="vlek4">
<div id="jsandjq"><img src="img/js&jq.png" width="576" height="104" /></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code I use for 1 of the buttons:

```
#vlek4{
    background-image:url(../img/vlek4.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:980px;
    left:600px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.2s;
    transition-duration: 1.2s;
}

#vlek4:hover{
    position:absolute;
    left:542px;
    width:;
    height:;
}

#vlek4 #jsandjq{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-460px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;
    opacity:0;
}

#vlek4:hover #jsandjq{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:-460px;
    width:163px;
    height:113px;

    opacity:1;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#vlek4:hover #jsandjq:hover img{
display:none;
visibility:hidden;}
```

Vlek4 stands for the JS & Jquery button.
jsandjq stands for the image that gets shown.

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong here?
The problem shows up in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can't really make a jsFiddle for this. It's kinda biggy! hehe..

Comment: What exactly you need?? to disable the image on hover?

Comment: well, I do not want to see the image if I hover over the empty spot. It does shows up when you hover over it right now. I thought the #vlek4:hover #jsandjq:hover would disable it, but it's still there!

Comment: In my case (FF 21.0) it seems to be working fine. What browsers have you tested it in?

Comment: please check it up in chrome. that's where the problem is. Will edit my question aswell for Chrome.

Comment: Version 27.0.1453.94 m - Google Chrome

Comment: the main point of writing css is to increase your level of patience and observation. Sherlock holmes also studied css, well grapholgy is a form of real lyf css.

Comment: Nice  thinking! And I did everything to fix this. But can't find it.. So my patience is kinda gone now!

Comment: Works perfectly. It is disappeared when nothing exists, on hover it slowly comes and goes off on mouse out. What version of Firefox are you using? Your chrome is same as mine and works perfectly. - @RyandeVries

Comment: But hover over the spot where the image is when you cannot see it. it will show up that I do not want

Comment: so in chrome, I see 3 buttons, html css and jquery/ java script? is that correct? or shouldt it be there? Underneath those buttons there is a space. If I hover one of those buttons in that empty space there appears a new picture. Is that correct? Or shouldnt appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are writing hover effect to entire div which includes hidden image as well.

Place the image out of the hover div.

```
<div id="vlek1">
          <div id="html"> <img src="img/html.png" width="576" height="104"> <!--Place this outside of the parent div--></div>  
 </div>
```

---

**Method 2**

Instead of `opacity` use `visibility` . In this case you need not to change the HTML.

**[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Uady/1/)** (Scroll to the bottom of the output panel)

---

Change `.vierkant div` to `.vierkant > div` Since it is pointing to the all divs inside the `.vierkant` the transition effect is clashing so make it only for the first div of the `.vierkant`

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3Uady/4/)**

Comment: It is almost fixed! I did change to opacity to visibility, but at another spot. I will update and show you what I changed. The change is in the last collum of the css. Also uploaded the new css aswell

Comment: if I do what you did, change the opacity  on both, it won't show anymore while hovering the button

Comment: going to try it again then!

Comment: it's updated. As you can see there is no transition in it anymore that I would like to keep. But the other part is helpen yes!

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/3Uady/2/ transition is working fine when icons are outside the pop up. The problem is when it is in that pop up div.

Comment: Yep, you are right. So it has to be some other code.. yug! Got an idea how to fix this? by stopping the rest of the code for just these 3 elements? if something like this is even possible..

Comment: @RyandeVries Finally got the solution :) wil update the answer

Comment: great great great!!! Wish I could accept your awnser 15 times instead of just 1. I just have a last question, what does it mean a ">" between vierkant and div?

Comment: > points to the direct child div of the .vierkant div. You can check this [article](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/css-selectors.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks alot, aswell for the explanation. If you would like to see the article with the right css. It's updated right now! ;)